# The End time and RRULE doesn't work correctly

Tags: icalendar

Here there are 2 events for to add in calendar.

The first event details

1. SUMMARY:Class: ACCT 1001  1 Lecture(1829)
2. Start date and time: 30/08/2012 and 3.00 PM
3. End date: 12/12/2012 and 3.50 PM
4. MO,WE,FR only these days need to set in the date range(doesn't need to set all day).

below is my ics format:

> `BEGIN:VCALENDAR
>   PRODID:-//bashmoblie v0.1//NONSGML iCal Writer//EN
>   VERSION:2.0
>   CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
>   METHOD:PUBLISH
>   BEGIN:VEVENT
>   DTSTART:20120830T150000
>   RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20121212T155000;WKST=SU;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR
>   DTSTAMP:20091130T213238Z
>        UID:1285935469767a7c7c1a9b3f0df8003a@yoursever.com
>        CREATED:20091130T213238Z
>   SUMMARY:Class: ACCT 1001  1 Lecture(1829)
>   LAST-MODIFIED:20091130T213238Z
>        EQUENCE:0
>        STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   SUMMARY:Class: ACCT 1001  1 Lecture(1829)
>   LOCATION:Title:  Introduction to Accounting(Lecture)
>   TRANSP:OPAQUE
>   END:VEVENT
>   BEGIN:VEVENT
>   DTSTART:20120830T170000
>   RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20121212T175000;WKST=SU;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR
>   DTSTAMP:20091130T213238Z
>        UID:1285935469767a7c7c1a9b3f0df8003a@yoursever.com
>        CREATED:20091130T213238Z
>   SUMMARY:Class: SOC 180  1 Lecture(1378)
>   LAST-MODIFIED:20091130T213238Z
>        EQUENCE:0
>        STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   SUMMARY:Class: SOC 180  1 Lecture(1378)
>   LOCATION:Title:  World Pop Probs(Lecture)
>   TRANSP:OPAQUE
>   END:VEVENT
>   END:VCALENDAR`

The problem with this is doesn't correct the end time(start time: 3 pm and end time is 3 pm). Here the start and end time are same and the rrule(MO,WE,FR) in the week is set not correctly now.

Please any one can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try validating your ics with an online validator, there seems to be quite a few typos in it (http://icalvalid.cloudapp.net/Default.aspx).

also can you clarify what you mean 
End date: 12/12/2012 and 3.50 PM ? do you mean your even is every mo, we, fr from 3:00pm to 3:50pm ? then you should either define a duration propery or define a dtend=20120830T155000

making assumptions about your intention, it looks like you are confusing the dtend with until properties.